# maple plot directional field without detools

Tags: plot, maple

This is a homework problem. I am to plot the directional field of the ode y' = x*y/2 using for loops and or procs. I have the following code:

```
X := [seq(.1*x, x = -20 .. 20)]; 
Y := [seq(y, y = -2 .. 2, .1)]; 
P := Array([seq(0, x = 0 .. 41^2-1)]);
with(plots); 
for k to 41 do for j to 41 do
slope := (1/2)*X[k]*Y[j]; 
Xp := [X[k], X[k]+.1]; Yp := [Y[j], Y[j]+0.1*slope]; 
P[41*(k-1)+j] := plot(Xp, Yp) end do end do;
display(P);
```

and get something really awful looking which isn't right.I understand it a lot of plots and would be easier to use detools but as stated it's for homework. I get something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UArMP.png

Comment: Word of advice: be careful with not being consistent with the semi-colons (`;`). Also, indenting code makes it much more readable. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see why the `display(P)` looks wrong if you do `display(P[1..2])` - it is a "window of plot windows".

You need to tell Maple that P is not *one* object but that the display should be of 1681 plots, e.g. with the sequence functional.

```
display(seq(P[i], i = 1..numelems(P)));
```

[image: Directional field]